# If $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^+$, prove that $\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}+\sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2}\ge\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

When I was doing Math Training, the coach gave a inequality problem.

> If $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^+$, prove that $$\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}+\sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2}\ge\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}.$$

I tried to use the brute force method, and found out it was to hard and it involves lot of terms.

The coach later said that there is a beautiful way to solve this problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: Trigonometry, law of cosine, $60^\circ$ and $120^\circ$, sum of two sides of a triangle is no less than the third side.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820957, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1187798 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2-xz%2Bz%5E2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7By%5E2-yz%2Bz%5E2%7D%5Cge%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2Bxy%2By%5E2%7D.%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: After one times squaring we get
$$2\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}\sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2}\geq xz+yz+xy-2z^2$$
Squaring again and factorizing we obtain
$$(xy-xz-yz)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - did you really found the factorization yourself? (It's not supposed to be a hate question)

Comment: We have solved this inequality in our Math-camp. I gave many talks About inequalities.